# mean io end to end example in google app engine

Tags: cloud, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm trying to play with http://mean.io/. I'm looking for a good tutorial to see an end to end basic webapp running, I'm sure there's one out there! anyone? 
Also, I know google chose it as one of the frameworks for google apps engine, is there an example for that? Deploying and running a meanio based web app?

Answer (score 1):

so far i found this video explaining the how to deploy mean-stack on Google Compute Engine.

["Click to Deploy" the mean stack on Google Cloud Platform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSVQVauLezA&index=4&list=PLhNnMgaEymovR4f0ct_NZPWdYekQmK4za)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my collection of Angular tutorials and generators and generators with tutorials - all of which can be used to get started making an app.  As soon as I hear of one that covers Google app engine deployment specifically, I'll indicate that in the building and development section

http://www.dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters/